# Xamarin ios Building app for release

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I've been getting this all day when trying to build the app. I've deleted the bin/obj folders, updated to the beta channel. restarted multiple times. it will build in debug mode. I had the same issue trying to do it from Visual studio. Has anyone had this recently and if so what do i need to do to get it to build.

[image]

Comment: How long have you tried and waited for a Release build? They take a while.

Comment: I had the same problem when working on a Xamarin.Android project last week. Randomly the release builds started to hang at the same point as yours (I waited for over 30 minutes once, so it definitely was stuck). I think that the only way to fix it temporarily was to restart Xamarin Studio or the whole OS. Unfortunately, I don't have an answer but seems to me that this is a bug in Xamarin Studio. Which version are you using?

Comment: Ye it was around half an hour, left it building over lunch with no joy. I'm using xamarin studio 6.1.5. Ye, im just restarting, deleting bins/obj folders. Its no problem in debug with a simulator. evidentiy same issue is happening with trying to deploy to a handset